# Using Django ORM outside of Django throws ImportError on assigning to the FK

Tags: django, orm, shell, django-models, importerror

When using the Django ORM from an external shell, using a model with a ForeignKey field an ImportError is thrown when assigning to it.

And here is a paste of my shell sessions both from ./manage.py shell and from normal python shell.

```
bradyrj@machine:~/workspaces/django/shellgame$ python manage.py shell
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 15 2010, 15:52:39)
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from shells.models import Location, Shell
>>> okinawa = Location()
>>> okinawa.title = "Okinawa"
>>> okinawa.description = "Island south of main Japanese Islands, in the Ryukyu Island chain."
>>> okinawa.save()
>>> s = Shell()
>>> s.title = "Conch"
>>> s.description = "it's just a friggin shell"
>>> s.location_found = okinawa
>>> s.save()
>>>
[1]+ Stopped python manage.py shell


bradyrj@machine:~/workspaces/django/shellgame$ cd ../
bradyrj@machine:~/workspaces/django$ cd ../
bradyrj@machine:~/workspaces$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 15 2010, 15:52:39)
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> import sys
>>> os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = 'shellgame.settings'
>>> sys.path.append('/home/bradyrj/workspaces/django')
>>> from shellgame.shells.models import Shell, Location
>>> nc = Location()
>>> nc.title = "Pine Knoll Shores"
>>> nc.description = "best beaches"
>>> nc.save()
>>> s = Shell()
>>> s.title = "shark tooth"
>>> s.description = "old, small, arrowhead-like"
>>> s.location_found = nc
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 354, in __set__
val = getattr(value, self.field.rel.get_related_field().attname)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 758, in get_related_field
data = self.to._meta.get_field_by_name(self.field_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 291, in get_field_by_name
cache = self.init_name_map()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 321, in init_name_map
for f, model in self.get_all_related_m2m_objects_with_model():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 396, in get_all_related_m2m_objects_with_model
cache = self._fill_related_many_to_many_cache()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 410, in _fill_related_many_to_many_cache
for klass in get_models():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 167, in get_models
self._populate()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 61, in _populate
self.load_app(app_name, True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 76, in load_app
app_module = import_module(app_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named shells
>>>
```

Here's a repo with the source code with the project: https://bitbucket.org/ryanbrady/shellgame/src

Comment: First, the exception is thrown when you assign a FK field, not when you save. Second, `shellgame` is obviously missing in the path. Why don't you just inspect `sys.path` in the Django shell and reproduce it in your own Python shell?

Comment: The django project directory and the immediate directory are both on the path.  Does every directory in the entire django project need to be on the path too?

Comment: @RJBrady: In the Django shell, you were able to import from `shells.models`. So I think only `/home/bradyrj/workspaces/django/shellgame` was missing in the path of your Python shell.

Comment: @RJBrady: You could also make use of the function `setup_environ` from `django.core.management` (in `__init__.py`). This is what `manage.py` effectively does.

Comment: I did try the setup_environ earlier and it still had the same error.  It did add the app directory to the path, but only adding the "project.appname" to the installed apps made any difference.

Comment: @RJBrady: Yes, `setup_environ` does not seem to really adjust the path for whatever reason. The point is, that the project directory is normally the first entry in `sys.path` in a Django shell. I could achieve this with `sys.path.insert(0, setup_environ(settings))` after I managed to load the settings module, and could then work with the models in my application.

Comment: @RJBrady: I just noticed that my configuration of installed apps is comparable to that of the answer below. According to http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/intro/tutorial01/#playing-with-the-api, it seems that both the project and the app have to be in the path if the app is not referred to by project.app in installed apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may fix it in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'shellgame.shells',
    ...
)
```

Comment: great. it is usually a problem on Linux as well :)